# Finding the value of current I

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have the question "For the circuit shown find the value of the current I"

[image]

From the previous question before this I worked out V = 60,

Therefore V = IR

And so I = V/R = 60/10 = 6A.

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's wrong.

Since the current will divide in parallel connections, there are different currents flowing through the branches those are \$I\$1, \$I\$2 and \$I\$3.

\$I\$ is the whole current supplied by the source. So you need to calculate all the branch currents and then **add them**.

That means you need to use KCL, \$I\$ = \$I\$1 + \$I\$2 + \$I\$3.

Comment: Thanks I got 10 A is this correct ? (:

Comment: @DanKhan Well done!! that's right :)

Answer (score 1):

60 V / 10 ohms gives the current through the 10 ohm resistor.

Is "I" a current that only flows through a 10 ohm resistor?

Comment: No I think it flows through all of the resistors ? Is that correct ? (:

Comment: No, I1 is 6A, but not I.   I=I1+I2+I3